# Storing and comparing a large quantity of Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, list, memory

My application stores a large number (about 700,000) of strings in an ArrayList. The strings are loaded from a text file like this:

```
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(750_000);

        //there's a try catch here but I omitted it for this example
        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(listPath), "UTF-8");
        while (fileIn.hasNext()) {
            String s = fileIn.nextLine().trim();

            if (s.isEmpty()) continue;
            if (s.startsWith("#")) continue;   //ignore comments

            stringList.add(s);
        }
        fileIn.close();
```

Later on, Other strings are compared to this list, using this code:

```
    String example = "Something";
    if (stringList.contains(example))
        doSomething();
```

This comparison will happen many hundreds (thousands?) of times.

---

This all works, but I want to know if there's anything I can do to make it better. I notice that the JVM increases in size from about 100MB to 600MB when it loads the 700K Strings. The strings are mainly about this size:

```
Blackened Recordings 
Divergent Series: Insurgent 
Google 
Pixels Movie Money 
X Ambassadors 
Power Path Pro Advanced 
CYRFZQ
```

Is there anything I can do to reduce the memory, or is that to be expected? Any suggestions in general?

Comment: `contains` is very slow method  ( `O(n)` )

Comment: [JEP 254](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254) / java 9 will bring compact strings; you can read there a few thoughts about string memory consumption and runtime perfomance.

Comment: A trie would help you here

Comment: @fge  for this problem, He wants to reduce the memory usage, why don't use `stream` with `filter` without storing the file contents?

Comment: @chengpohi performance! And a trie will take less memory than a list here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArrayList is a memory effective. Probably your issue is caused by **java.util.Scanner**. Scanner creates a lot of temp objects during parsing (Patterns, Matchers etc) and not suitable for big files.

Try to replace it with **java.io.BufferedReader**:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader fileIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("UTF-8"));
String line = null;
while ((line = fileIn.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.trim();

    if (line.isEmpty()) continue;
    if (line.startsWith("#")) continue;   //ignore comments

    stringList.add(line);
}
fileIn.close();
```

See [java.util.Scanner source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Scanner.java)

To pinpoint memory issue attach to your JVM any memory profiler, for example [VisualVM from JDK tools](https://visualvm.java.net/).

**Added:**

Let's make few assumtions:

1. you have 700000 string with 20 characters each.
2. object reference size is 32 bits, object header - 24, array header - 16, char - 16, int 32.

Then every string will consume 24+32*2+32+(16+20*16) = 456 bits.

Whole ArrayList with string object will consume about 700000*(32*2+456) = 364000000 bits = **43.4 MB** (very roughly).

Comment: yeah, you're right, the original question is about memory consumption.

Comment: ArrayList is memory effective. Probably most of object allocations are caused by "java.util.Scanner", which allocates a lot of Mather's and Pattern's during parsing. (see source code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Scanner.java).

Comment: @Viktor You mentioned a good point. OP should determine the memory issue more detailed.

Comment: I'm going to try the other suggestions with the HashSet/HashMap's too, but using a BufferedReader made an incredible difference. It only jumped up by maybe 70MB instead of 500MB. My program right now is using up about 189MB vs the 600MB it used before. Thank you @Viktor !

Answer (score 2):

Not quite an answer, but:
Your scenario uses around 70mb on my machine:

```
long usedMemory = -(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
{//
    String[] strings = new String[700_000];
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        strings[i] = new String(new char[20]);
    }
}//
usedMemory += Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
System.out.println(usedMemory / 1_000_000d + " mb");
```

How did you reach 500mb there? As far as I know, `String` has internally a `char[]`, and each `char` has 16 bits. Taking the `Object` and `String` overhead in account, 500mb is still quite much for the strings only. You may perform some benchmarking tests on your machine.

As others already mentioned, you should change the datastructure for element look-ups/comparison.

Comment: Let's assume that object reference takes 32 bits, object header - 24, array header - 16, char -16, int - 32.

String with 20 characters would contains 2 int fields, 1 object reference to char array: 16+16+32+16+20*16 = 400 bits.

ArrayList backed by array than can be twice bigger than ArraList size: [some ArrayList fields, do not care] + 700'000*2*32 + 400*70000 ~ 324800000 bits ~ **40 MB**.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **Trie** data structure which can be used as dictionary, with so many strings they can occur multiple times. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie . It seems to fit your case.

UPDATE:
An alternative can be **HashSet** or **HashMap** string -> something if you want occurrences of strings for example. Hashed collection will be faster than list for sure.

I would start with HashSet.

Comment: ``HashSet`` makes more sense here than ``HashMap`` as there is no associated data

Comment: Yes I modified post, lately I was doing something similar to case and wrote update too fast ;). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're likely going to be better off using a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) instead of an `ArrayList` as both `add` and `contains` are constant time operations in a HashSet.

However, it does assume that your object's `hashCode` implementation (which is part of Object, but can be overridden) is evenly distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Using an `ArrayList` is a very bad idea for your use case, because it is not sorted, and hence you cannot efficiently search for an entry.

The best built-in type for your case is a is a `TreeSet<String>`. It guarantees O(log(n)) Performance for `add()` and `contains()`.

Be aware that TreeSet is not thread-safe in the basic implementation. Use an mt-safe wrapper (see the JavaDocs of TreeSet for this).

Comment: OP want to check if exists/contains, not to sort. Hashed set is faster. I am afraid that with sorted array it would be the same O(n) time in the worst case

Comment: exist/contains works only fast if the data is sorted. That's why sorting matters. Btw the TreeSet needs no extra sort() call but keeps the collection sorted with every new insert.

Comment: Really ?:) so why hashed collection are not sorted and contains is O(1) and tree set contains O(log(n)) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Java 8 approach. It uses [Files.lines()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) method which take advantage of Stream API. This method reads all lines from a file as a Stream.
As a consequence no String objects are created till the terminal operation which is a static method **MyExecutor.doSomething(String)**.

```
/**
* Process lines from a file.
* Uses Files.lines() method which take advantage of Stream API introduced in Java 8.
*/
private static void processStringsFromFile(final Path file) {
 try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(file)) {
   lines.map(s -> s.trim())
     .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
     .filter(s -> !s.startsWith("#"))
     .filter(s -> s.contains("Something"))
     .forEach(MyExecutor::doSomething);
 } catch (IOException ex) {
     logProcessStringsFailed(ex);        
 }
}
```

I conducted an [Analysis of Memory Usage](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/profiler-intro.html#memory) in NetBeans and here are the Memory Results for empty implementation of **doSomething()**

```
public static void doSomething(final String s) {

}
```

Live Bytes = 6702720 ≈ **6.4MB**.